# Pandas: bit shift operator (>>) on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to figure out how to bit shift values in a pandas column.

What I'd like to do looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 5]})
df['val'] = ((x << 1) * math.pi
```

Results in:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'Series' and 'int'
```

What's the proper format for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `numpy`

```
(df.x.values<<1)*math.pi
Out[354]: array([ 6.28318531, 12.56637061, 18.84955592])
#df['val']=(df.x.values<<1)*math.pi
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to numpy. This can alternatively be done with `np.left_shift(df.x, 1) * math.pi`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for. I don't think bit-shifting is vectorized:

`df['val'] = (df['x'].apply(lambda x: x << 1))*math.pi`

Output:

```
   x  y        val
0  1  3   6.283185
1  2  4  12.566371
2  3  5  18.849556
```